# Quickly expose class properties as bindable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a class that I am binding to my view model. It is basically a struct full of displayable strings for the UI:

```
class DisplayVO
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    // ... about a dozen more properties 
}
```

Basically the `DisplayVO` wraps a bunch of properties that are bound to the UI. This works until one portion of the UI modifies a property (e.g. the user can edit the `Description`) so I want to update the UI with the new modifications.

So what I would normally do is implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and override each `set` method to broadcast `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));`

I'm feeling lazy - is there a way to have this done for all members of the class? In Flex I could do:

```
[Bindable]
public class DisplayVO
{
    private var Title:String;
    private var Description:String;
}
```

and magically all of the properties of `DisplayVO` would be wrapped to automatically broadcast changes without me having to write all of the boilerplate. Is there an equivalent for C# and WPF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better way to trigger OnPropertyChanged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063902/better-way-to-trigger-onpropertychanged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out NotifyPropertyWeaver http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver it runs a post build task which does exactly what you are after.

Comment: I don't necessarily like that it is post build but it is the closest to what I was after so that is good enough for a check mark. I've actually just gone ahead and written the boilerplate by hand. Only a few properties actually get mutated after initialization (and require UI redraws) so I can live with the code bloat for now.

Answer (score 1):

you could write a snippet that fills in the boilerplate. Here's one that I use ( I have a method, OnPropertyChanged() that broadcasts the event:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <Header>
    <Title>ObservableProperty</Title>
    <Author>Scott Austen</Author>
    <Shortcut>#ObsProp</Shortcut>
    <Description>Inserts property definition with private backing field, calling RaisePropertyChanged</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Declarations>
      <Literal>
        <ID>Type</ID>
        <Default>Type</Default>
      </Literal>
      <Literal>
        <ID>PropertyName</ID>
        <Default>P</Default>
      </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="CSharp">
      <![CDATA[public $Type$ $PropertyName$
      {
        get { return _$PropertyName$; }
        set
        {
          _$PropertyName$ = value;          
          OnPropertyChanged("$PropertyName$");
        }
      }

      private $Type$ _$PropertyName$;]]>
    </Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

then all you need to do is type `obsprop TAB TAB {type} TAB TAB {propertyName} ENTER.`

Comment: That's a pretty shoddy implementation though, the event is fired even though the property may not even have changed as the name of the event states.

Comment: I haven't found it to be an issue. Other than a minor performance gain what are the benefits of checking for changes?

Comment: That the event is only fired when it *should* be, doing it your way is like firing a downloaded event even when the download is not done yet, it's semantially incorrect and can cause trouble to whoever wants to use the event.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I only use the propertychanged event to allow binding to a wpf control - the worst that could happen is the ui gets refreshed too many times. As an aside (though this doesn't prove my point) the way I've posted is the way microsoft recommends to implement property change notification for binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Comment: I've never seen that article, i usually recommend [that one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) which does it as i would expect it.

Comment: Stalemate! Again, this hasn't yet caused me problems, but I agree that your way is semantically more correct.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Property Declaration snippet that calls OnPropertyChanged.  It also populates some Attributes from the  System.ComponentModel name space...

```
 Description: a brief phrase about what the property does
 DisplayName: how the property should be labelled 
 DefaultValue: the initial value of the property
```

This snippet also uses the DebuggerStepThroughAttribute so that the debugger will not enter the getter and setter, but this should be removed if you don't want that effect...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Full property declaration</Title>
            <Shortcut>propfull</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for property and backing field</Description>
            <Author>GJV</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>string</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>property</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyProperty</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>field</ID>
            <ToolTip>The variable backing this property</ToolTip>
                    <Default>myProperty</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>desc</ID>
                    <ToolTip>What the property is about</ToolTip>
                    <Default>My description...</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>dispname</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Column header</ToolTip>
                    <Default>DisplayName</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>defaultvalue</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Default value</ToolTip>
                    <Default>""</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[private $type$ $field$;
    [Description("$desc$"), DisplayName("$dispname$"), DefaultValue($defaultvalue$)]
    public $type$ $property$
    {
            [DebuggerStepThrough]get{return $field$;}
            [DebuggerStepThrough]set
            {
                if(value!=$field$)
                {
                    $field$ = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("$property$");
                }
            }
    }
    $end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

The Description Attribute is meant to be extracted and used for ToolTip text, but it can also provide some documentation value.

This snippet assumes that your base view model class has a method like this...

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if(PropertyChanged!=null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```